# Best method of finding random English words

Tags: android, random, arraylist

I'm looking for the best way to find a random English word using an Android app. Is there a better way than saving a .txt file with all the words in your res/ folder, such as

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments/dictionary.txt

then importing it into an ArrayList? The app I'm developing will search for words quite often, such as a random word starting with the letters 'A' or 'Be'. I'm worried about memory and runtime with this function.

Answer (score 2):

Create a SQLite database containing all the words. You can then query that database using SQL to match your random word with various starting letters.

SQLite Details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Look for documentation on using LIKE in SQL for your text matching.

Example: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

For randomness, find all words matching your criteria. Get the count of them (call it 'n'), then pick a random number 'x' between 1 and n, and take the xth record.

Answer (score 0):

Use a prefix tree (or Trie) as described [here](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/coding-up-trie-prefix-tree.html).

It's extremly efficient, as all word-beginnings are only stored once.